# Python - x not in list error

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list inside a list and I am trying to remove any values in side the nested list that are equal to -1. I am getting a "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list" error when I try to run my code, any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
for x in list:
    for i in x:
        if i == -1:
            list.remove(x)
```

Comment: Maybe `-1` occurs more than once in `x`. But anyway, you can't remove elements from `list` while iterating over it.

Comment: @SteveJessop, unfortunately you _can_ but it hardly ever gives the expected result (unless you really really know what to expect)

Comment: @gnibbler: OK, so the behaviour is defined by the language then? Skips an element, or whatever?

Comment: @SteveJessop, that's certainly what happens for cpython. I'm not sure it's in the language definition though. Compared to dict, which is not allowed to have a different size between iterations.

Comment: @gnibbler: well, if Python is ever standardized then we'll find out ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate a list while iterating over it. You also shouldn't name a variable `list`, since that name is used by a built-in function. You can achieve what you want via a simple [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
my_list = [[x for x in v if x != -1] for v in my_list]
```

Comment: Surely `[x for x in my_list if -1 not in x]`?

Comment: @SteveJessop On second thought, isn't that different? Note that my `x` is not the same as the OP's `x`.

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake in what I commented, now fixed. My code *is* different from yours, I believe that your code is different from what the questioner wants. The idea is to remove from the outer list, any inner list that contains -1. Your code removes the -1s from the inner lists.

Comment: @SteveJessop *"I have a list inside a list and I am trying to **remove any values in side the nested list that are equal to -1**"*

Comment: @arshajii, but it's hard to see how that matches what the code is suggesting. Maybe just put both interpretations into your answer

Comment: Ah right, didn't notice that. So basically you're believing the text and concluding that the questioner's code is completely off. Whereas I believed the code and concluded it was only slightly off :-)

Comment: I think I can settle this, the code that @arshajii wrote is what I am looking for. I am trying to remove any -1s from the inner list. The outer list just contains the inner lists.

Comment: @JacobMammoliti: good. Note that arshajii's code doesn't modify the inner lists, it creates new lists based on them. This is normally a good thing, but if you actually need to mutate the inner lists for some reason then you could do `for v in my_list: v[:] = [x for x in v if x != -1]`. Slice assignment modifies the list in place, meaning that if someone else has a reference to it then they see the changes.

Comment: @SteveJessop great, thanks for explaining. This helps me a lot more now.